# Pandas Dataframe - Rate Calculation

Tags: pandas

In the below csv I have 3 columns - Pass,Sex,Age. 1- Denotes Pass and 0 - Denotes Fail.I am trying to calculate the % of Female candidates who have passed and % of female candidates who has failed.

I dont want to convert this into a series and then calculate - I want to use pandas - groupby or loc functionalities.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyT6j.jpg)

How to do this?

Comment: `df['Pass'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df['Sex'] == 'female'].Pass.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
```